# PHP proxy for cross-domain AJAX scripting

Tags: php, cross-domain

I have set up a simple php proxy

```
 $proxy = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8080';

 $context = array(
    'http' => array(
               'proxy' => $proxy,
               'request_fulluri' => True,
    ),
 );

 $context = stream_context_create($context);

 $body = file_get_contents("http://www.php.net", False, $context);
 print $body
```

I want to be able to make ajax request from one subdomain to another. Unfortunately the code above does not work yet. When I make an request the script loads for a long time without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I do only `$body = file_get_contents("http://www.php.net"); print $body;` then it is working and yours is working too

Comment: what error? on error.log

Comment: thanks, $body = file_get_contents("http://www.php.net"); worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you understood AJAX proxy correctly. Check out [this article](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html), it's stated there that PHP script itself is a proxy, so there's no need to use tcp proxy via streams.